# Replace values in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following python code:

```
consumos=df.iloc[:,0]

df['media_movel'] = rolling_median(consumos, window=30, center=True).fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')
desv_padrao=df.stack().std()
threshold = 1000
difference = np.abs(consumos - df['media_movel'])

corr=np.abs(df['media_movel']-desv_padrao)
df['corr']=pd.DataFrame(corr)


outlier = difference > threshold
df.mask(outlier, df['corr'], axis=1)
```

So, I have a dataframe containing a time series and my aim is to correct the outliers (by admiting that the difference between the reference data and the rolling median has to be greater than 1000, which is the threshold).

For that, I've created the boolean variable `outlier`(which is True when there is an outlier based on the previous explanation) and I am trying to replace those outliers with: (rolling mediam column - standard deviation) into a mask, but the result is the time series with NaNs. I don't know why those NaNs appear, but I need to obtain the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the replacement of the masked values may be failing due to a shape mismatch. Try replacing your last line with this:

```
df.mask(outlier, df['corr'].values.reshape(-1, 1), axis=1)
```

If that fails, try this:

```
df.iloc[:,0].mask(outlier, df['corr'].values.reshape(-1, 1), axis=1)
```

Comment: None of these options work. In the first case I get: ValueError: other must be the same shape as self when an ndarray
In the second case in get: ValueError: Length of replacements must equal series length.

Comment: What is returned by these two expressions: `df.shape` and `df['corr'].shape`?